# getting bs4 on chromebook

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, importerror

So when I attempt to install bs4 on my chromebook it says that it worked no problem:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your 
Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in 
January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove 
support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve<2.0,>1.2; python_version < "3.0" in 
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools-lru-cache; python_version < "3" in 
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from soupsieve<2.0,>1.2; python_version < "3.0"- 
>beautifulsoup4) (1.6.1)
```

but when I try to import it I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'bs4'
```

Any advice?

Comment: Out of curiosity could you run `python --version` or `python3 --version` - however you're calling python on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should not be "beautifulsoup4", try `pip install bs4` instead. If that does not work, try to install the package via anaconda3 if you are currently using it.